# Split-screen in Godot 3D with a single Scene containing 2 cameras

Tags: viewport, godot, split-screen

I am new to Godot, transitioning from Unity and I still do not have a good grasp on how scenes and viewports interact. I am making a game with two players: one pilots an aircraft and the other shoots a turret on top of it. Each player has a different camera, so I want the game to be split-screen. Most tutorials for Godot 3D implement split-screens like this:

```
Spatial
    Viewport1
        Player1
           Camera1
    Viewport2
        Player2
           Camera2
```

However, that solution does not work for me because it separates the cameras, and I would like to have both cameras together in a single scene like this:

```
Player
    Body
        Camera1
    Turret
        Camera2
```

I tried this:

```
Control
    GridContainer
        Player
```

With the player already having 2 cameras as described previously, but only 1 camera gets displayed.
Is there any good way to implement this? Alternatively, I could make the body and the turret separate scenes and make them follow each other with code, but getting them together in a single scene simplifies other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly the setters for the `Camera`(`3D`) in `Viewport` are not exposed to scripting (this is because we are supposed to use the `current` property on the `Camera`(`3D`)).

But we can do the change at a lower level by calling [`viewport_attach_camera`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_renderingserver.html#class-renderingserver-method-viewport-attach-camera) on the `RenderingServer` (in Godot 4) or `VisualServer` (in Godot 3) to change the current `Camera`(`3D`) of the `Viewport` to an arbitrary one with .

The method wants the `RID` (Resource ID) of the `Viewport` (which you get by calling `get_viewport_rid` on it) and of the `Camera`(`3D`) (which you can get by calling `get_camera_rid()` on it).

This also means that the code that does this setup must be able to reference both the `Viewport` and its intended `Camera`(`3D`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Theraot for answering the question! So the final implementation looked like this:

```
Main
   Player
   GridContainer
       SubViewportContainer
            SubViewport
       SubViewportContainer
            SubViewport
```

The player had 2 cameras, like so:

```
Player
    Camera3D
    Turret
        Camera3D2
```

And I added this script to the GridContainer, which sets up the split-screen:

```
extends GridContainer


@onready var viewport1: SubViewport = $SubViewportContainer/SubViewport
@onready var viewport2: SubViewport = $SubViewportContainer2/SubViewport
@onready var Camera1: Camera3D = get_node("../Player/Camera3D")
@onready var Camera2: Camera3D = get_node("../Player/Turret/Camera3D2")


func _ready():
    var Camera_rid1 = Camera1.get_camera_rid()
    var Camera_rid2 = Camera1.get_camera_rid()
    var viewport_rid1 = viewport1.get_viewport_rid()
    var viewport_rid2 = viewport2.get_viewport_rid()
    RenderingServer.viewport_attach_camera(viewport_rid1, Camera_rid1)
    RenderingServer.viewport_attach_camera(viewport_rid2, Camera_rid2)
```